# Event to loaded page content (Ionic 2)?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am using NavController http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/ and I change page and I need to know when new page loaded, is there any event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, you have Lifecycle events in Ionic2 that you can take advantage of.

- ionViewDidLoad
- ionViewWillEnter
- ionViewDidEnter
- ionViewWillLeave
- ionViewDidLeave
- ionViewWillUnload

Example, you can find more info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events):

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("I'm alive!");
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    console.log("Looks like I'm about to leave :(");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I use it? like onPageLoaded() {console.log('page loaded')} ?

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: Note that in the current v2 nightly, the names start with `ionView` instead of `on`, eg `ionViewLoaded`.

Comment: I wanted to use `onPageLoaded` to hide the splashscreen manually, but I still end up closing it a bit before anything is displayed. Anyone having the same behavior?

Comment: The event namess were changed in 2.0.0-beta.8 (2016-06-06)

Answer (score 0):

who used angular2, can call ngAfterViewInit():

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // this.yourMethod
}
```