# Run function when an ionic 2 page has fully loaded

Tags: ios, iframe, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Is there a way to determine when an ionic 2 page has fully loaded? I need to insert some html into the page when all of the page html has been loaded. Ideally I would like to have a function in my @page class that runs when the page has been loaded.

At the moment I am inserting an iframe containing a vine into a div container. I am experiencing, when running the app on an iPhone 5 running iOS 9, some peculiar behaviour where the same vine sometimes sizes to the container and sometimes doesn't. I am guessing that this might be due to timing (the source for the vine iframe is received as part of an http request).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event to loaded page content (Ionic 2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944856/event-to-loaded-page-content-ionic-2)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `ionViewDidLoad` method:

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/somepage/somepage.html'
})
export class SomePage {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Put here the code you want to execute
  }
}
```

The lifecycle events as November 18, 2016 are:

- ionViewDidLoad
- ionViewWillEnter
- ionViewDidEnter
- ionViewWillLeave
- ionViewDidLeave
- ionViewWillUnload
- ionViewCanEnter

Since Ionic 2 is in active development, things change all the time. If you would like to check the current lifecycle events, please refer to: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried onPageLoaded but it runs when the index.html has loaded not when the somepage.html has loaded and that is what I need.

Comment: Ionic2 is in beta. functions change. it's now called "ionViewLoaded()"

Comment: Thanks for linking to lifecycle events

Comment: Hi are there this kind of functions for components ? Or how can I call function after the component is loaded? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ArmenSanoyan

Those events do not exist on 'inner' components. You need to use Angular's lifecycle events (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) instead of ionic's, or use something like the `@ViewChild` decorator in order to manage the child behaviour from the parent (http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/). But you know, theoretically each component should manage itself and shouldn't depend on parent. So, this `@Viewchild` thing is probably an anti-pattern. IF you can, I'll suggest you to use Angular's events. But of course, we need sometimes to take shortcuts :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use the lifecycle callback [ngAfterViewInit()](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html) of the component that is loaded last (depends on your routing).

Comment: Are there this kind of functions for components ?

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: If I am not mistaken  ngAfterViewInit() function get called after page is loaded but it doesn't work in components. So my question is are there functioins like ngAfterViewInit() which work in components too?

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is a component lifecycle method and therefore especially for components.